# Obtain the first element of the subelement of a vector in julia

Tags: julia

I created a 33-element Vector{Vector{Float64}} A in julia, where each element in the large vector is a 3-element Vector{Float64}. [a b c] [d e f] ...
I would like to slice the first element of each subelement and obtain a new Vector{Float64}, [a d ...]. Is it possible to achieve that with slicing but without for/while loops? Or is it only possible using loops? It would be ideal not to go through loops as the scale of the loop would increase up to 256-element sub vector and a 1000-element vector A.

A has the dimension (33,), and reshape doesn't work (as expected)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first element of each vector, you can do

```
julia> first.(A)
```

If you want the last element, it's

```
julia> last.(A)
```

and for the n'th element, use

```
julia> getindex.(A, n)
```

BTW, loops are very efficient, so there is no reason to avoid them, except, of course, that the broadcasted expressions above are more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You could do turning the vector of vectors into a matrix, and take the first row:

```
hcat(x...)[1, :]

2-element Vector{String}:
 "a"
 "d"
```

Comment: This does unnecessary allocations.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel can you expand on this please? :-)

Comment: Sure! Try `using BenchmarkTools;x = [rand(5) for _ in 1:10];` then `@btime first.($x)` takes 20ns and makes 1 allocation and `@btime hcat($x...)[1, :]` takes 500ns and makes 7 allocations. You create a structure with data not used later. Moreover `[1, :]` makes an additional copy (views are usually better).

Comment: But do not delete this answer as this now with the explanation will be useful for people learning Julia :)